# Proper indexing with postgres db

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I currently have a user model with multiple attributes, and I have couple of indexes on the user table.

However I'm using the paranoia gem, which automatically adds the deleted_at to the statement. Here is what I mean, if I search via email this is the statement :

```
SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = 'test@test.com' AND ("users".deleted_at IS NULL)
```

I have a index on email column, does this mean I should add a deleted_at column to the index as well to take advantage of the index or it will be fine just the way it is?

Comment: Specify the type of deleted_At and the count of records you have in this table.

Answer (score 2):

It'll be fine without an index. An email column is usually so, on a users table, that it's extremely selective already (and oftentimes unique), and it won't cost much to filter an occasional row out.

In contrast, I take it most users won't have been deleted, so you'll have very low selectivity when you'll be looking for a null value.

The index on deleted_at can be useful if you want to search users by deleted date, for instance. Or all deleted users, for that matter. In the latter cases, ask yourself if a long query for the occasional admin who needs it is worth the extra overhead on every row insert and update to maintain the index. (Not saying updating an index is slow, or course, but it does eventually add up.)

A more useful index in that sense, btw, would be a partial index on deleted_at:

```
create index on users (deleted_at) where (deleted_at is not null);
```

To use it, make sure you include a `where deleted_at is not null` in your where or join clause. It'll typically have a very low cardinalty and allow you to immediately find deleted rows, without adding trivial overhead on more typical database writes.

Answer (score 1):

Your query, using the current index, is going to lookup the value for the email in the index.  Then, for every matching record, it is going to fetch the record, get the value of deleted flag and optionally return the record.

In general, the location of different records for an email are going to be on different pages.

With the deleted flag in the index, it would only fetch the data that matches the `where` clause exactly.

So, the answer to your question depends on how many of the records have `NULL` versus non-`NULL` deleted flags.  If each email has, on average, 10 deleted records for each that is not deleted, then the current index will be reading 11 data pages when it only needs to read one.

If only a handful of records are deleted in the entire database, then this doesn't make a difference.

On balance, adding the `deleted` flag to the index is probably beneficial in the long term, as delete records pile up.